What happens when you avoid a blade barrier cast on you, but have nowhere to move?
Set-up for the question:
A size-category huge tiger (enlarged with Animal Growth) is charging down a hall towards enemies in a room just past the doorway (with enough room for the animal companion). There is a line of enemies, just waiting to strike. The tiger arrives, makes his attack, and the rest of the party is at the doorway, taking pot shots from between its legs.
The enemy cleric casts Blade Barrier right through the tiger's square. The tiger has improved evasion and makes the save. But, every square near the tiger is occupied.
Relevant rules:
The blade barrier spell reads:

If you evoke the barrier so that it appears where creatures are, each creature takes damage as if passing through the wall. Each such creature can avoid the wall (ending up on the side of its choice) and thus take no damage by making a successful Reflex save.

Questions:
What happens?

Does the tiger teleport beyond the line of enemies if it chooses that direction?
Does the tiger bull rush into them if it chooses that direction??
Does the tiger teleport behind its allies on the other side of the door if it chooses that direction?
Does the tiger share a square with its allies (and everyone is squeezing) if it chooses that direction?

Expected answer
I realize that this question does not have an answer spelled out in the rules. I guess I am looking for any way to interpret the rules that might come close to following the rules? Might be backed up in some way by the rules? The idea of the tiger teleporting to the first empty square doesn't seem likely, but plenty of other spells that cause a creature to move if they would avoid impediments wind up getting shunted to the first available square. So, I didn't want to rule it out. The DM had no clue how to adjudicate this situation, and decided the tiger was squeezing with the enemies, could not end his turn in a creature's square, so had to move as his first action on his turn, provoking attacks of opportunity, which seemed worse than just taking the blade barrier damage.

I think this is answerable with the rules — if I recall rules only prevented creatures to voluntary end their turn in another creature space. Because it's not a tiger turn, if I'm right I'll try to write answer using only the rules

Why do you think the tiger moves at all?
It can choose to be on either side of the barrier but there’s nothing to suggest that involves movement.

... because "The enemy cleric casts Blade Barrier right through the tiger's square"

@Peregrin no rule says you can’t be in the same square with a Blade Barrier.

Yeah, I still don't get it. The tiger's Huge, so it's space is 15 ft. x 15 ft. The caster picks a grid intersection so that the barrier cuts through the tiger's space. The tiger succeeds on its saving throw. I don't see how the tiger can both stay where it's at (i.e. not moving) and "end… up on the side of [the barrier of] its choice." I mean, unless the tiger is the animal companion of a druid named Schrödinger.
